# Ansible Win Disk Facts Module Returning Corrupted/Bad Formatted Facts Run on Windows EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, devops

I am running the Ansible win_disk_facts module (ansible 2.9.7) on an EC2 instance of Windows 2016 Server and getting other item data jumbled into my desired field output in the ansible_facts like below. It appears the module is parsing the disk facts incorrectly and I need the unique_id to run the rest of my playbook but am unable because of this jumbled output from the module. Anybody experience this with win_disk_facts module and have a workaround?

```
"ansible_facts": {
      "ansible_disks": [
         "serial_number": **"vol00a5480709157a1dd_00000001."**,
         "unique_id": **"vol00a5480709157a1dd_00001Amazon Elastic Block Store         1D0F"**
     ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is not an issue with the Ansible Win_Disk_Facts module, it is actually the way AWS returns Windows disk volume data from the server instance which you can see running with Powershell command Get-Disk UniqueID vole1d8gg4129043. To change the formatting to remove the extraneous AWS info and actually use the disk facts as output run this script on the server instance from the AWS site below:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-volumes.html